# Navigating from perspective to ortho pressing ALT not working anymore

Tags: navigation

So when navigating with Blender I can go from USER PERSPECTIVE to ortho view (front, back,etc) by pressing ALT, but for some reason this changed to just perspective or ortho. Meaning that if I'm in USER PERSPECTIVE by pressing ALT it just goes to perspective view (front, back, top), so I have to change to ORTHO USER to be able to use the ortho views by pressing ALT.
I want to know how I can revert this the way It used to be so that I can go from USER PERSEPCTIVE to ortho views without having to change the whole navigation view.

VIDEO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM6oOt9-GWM&ab_channel=PolyCrate

thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to use the Numpad - 1=Front, 3=Side, 7=Top, 9=Invert, 5=Toggle Ortho/User perspective.

Comment: I still don't understand why Blender changed this, when I revert to factory settings I'm able to go from USER PERSPECTIVE to ORTHO views with ALT without any issues. I don't know If it was something I might unintentionally pressed or If the program just got bugged.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to understand. As far as I know, even with factory settings, Alt (on its own) does nothing to change user/ortho perspective. How exactly did it work before? What version of blender was it? Things have been this way since at least 2.80 (I can't remember 2.79 and before and no longer have a version to check).

Comment: I'm running 1.93.5, here I uploaded a video to make it clear : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM6oOt9-GWM&ab_channel=PolyCrate

Comment: Oh, I see, For me it works if I'm already in the middle of a viewport orbit (middle mouse button pressed and mouse moving), then holding Alt - it snaps to the nearest ortho. when you "scroll by" it. Is this it? If I hold Alt first and then try orbiting, I get a timeline scrub instead.

Comment: Yes, but the snapping doesn't go to ortho view but perspective, like shown in the video. The only way to make it work is to revert to factory settings, but when I restart the program the issue comes back again even If I save It as a startup file. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I can't seem to be able to reproduce that, so I don't think I can be much help.  It's strange that it survives a startup save.

Comment: It is, I had to go into the blender file settings and delete the folder to do a clean swipe. It was the only way I found to solve the problem, I really hope It doesn't come back.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by going to *Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan* check "Auto Perspective" parameter.

And voila <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> goes to ortho and perspective when you move mouse navigation view normally.